# What is the way to run a new thread and a UI thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

As far as I can understand in android when we are running processes they start off in the Main thread. When we are doing some heavier work we use a new thread. If we like to modify the UI appearance we use the run on UI.

Can someone explain to me what these threads do and how they are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI thread and the main thread are just different names for the same thread.

All of the UI inflation for an application is done on this main thread.  The reason we delegate "heavier" work to other threads is because we do not want those operations to slow the responsiveness and inflation time of the UI.

You will want to run any operations that change the UI or modify objects used by the UI on the main thread.

An example with an AsyncTask

```
package com.wolfdev.warriormail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button loginButton;
    private EditText eText;
    private EditText pText;
    private CheckBox box;
    private String user; 
    private String pass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

            //Initialize UI objects on main thread
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        eText.clearFocus();
        pText.clearFocus();
        Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeanimation);
        Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slideanimation);
        eText.startAnimation(slideIn);
        pText.startAnimation(slideIn);
        box = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        box.startAnimation(fadeIn);
        login.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        user = email.getText().toString();
        password = pass.getText().toString();

    }

    class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... args){
                    /* Here is where you would do a heavy operation
                    *  In this case, I want to validate a users
                    *  credentials.  If I would do this on the main
                    *  thread, it would freeze the UI.  Also since
                    *  this is networking, I am forced to do this on
                    *  a different thread.
                    */

                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                     /* This function actually runs on the main
                     * thread, so here I notify the user if the
                     * login was successful or if it failed.  If
                     * you want update the UI while in the background
                     * or from another thread completely, you need to
                     * use a handler.
                     */
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand it in theory however I would like to see some examples. Could you kindly provide some from your code.
Like code where you would do something on the main thread, then do something on another thread, then get back and edit the UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'd research the following two things:

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

This is a pretty good resource for Android threading. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Also, if you're asking because you'll be fetching some data / making simple API calls, I'd definitely recommend checking out http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. This will make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: This, AsyncTask will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Note these threads should never be running for more than a few seconds!

Answer (score 2):

The main `Thread` is the `UI Thread`. So when you start your `Activity` you are on the `Main (UI) Thread`. When you want to use a separate thread to do "heavy work" such as network processes then you have several options. You may create a separate `Thread` inside your `Activity` and call runOnUiThread to update your `UI`. You could also use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for short lived operations. According to the docs, things that may only take a few seconds. Here's a short example of that:

```
public class TalkToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
//do your work here
    return something;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
       // do something with data here-display it or send to mainactivity
```

and you would call it from

```
TalkToServer myAsync = new TalkToServer() //can add params if you have a constructor  
myAsync.execute() //can pass params here for `doInBackground()` method
```

Just make sure not to try and update `UI` in `doInBackground()` method. Use any of the others or passs the data back to `Activity` method. If your `AsyncTask` class is innner method of `Activity` then you can use its `context` for updating `UI`. If it is in its own file then you will need to pass `context` to its constructor like

```
TalkToServer myAsync = new TalkToServer(this);
```

You also may want to read this

[Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)