# the class extends AsyncTask won't start

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm new at this site, and i'm new at android programing, so you have to be a litle patient whith me. 
I start an app to connect with a mysql database, but the asynctask won't start, the app just stop right before the class, and i really don't know why. so could you help me?
This is my code:

```
public class Logar extends Activity {
EditText etUsuario, etSenha;
Button btLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logar);

    etUsuario=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsuario);
    etSenha=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
    btLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



    btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("logar", "entrou no evento");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario",etUsuario.getText().toString()));
            parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha",etSenha.getText().toString()));
            Log.i("logar", "parametrosPost.add");



        }




class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String urlPost="http://192.168.1.131/android/logar.php";
    String urlGet="http://192.168.1.131/android/logar.php?usuario="+etUsuario.getText().toString()+"&senha="+etSenha.getText().toString();
    String respostaRetornada = null;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args){
            Log.i("logar", "vai entrar no try");
            try {
                respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost, parametrosPost);
                //respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpGet(urlGet);
                String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
                Log.i("logar", "resposta = "+resposta);
                resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                if (resposta.equals("1"))
                     startActivity(new Intent(Logar.this,MenuPrincipal.class));
                    //mensagemExibir("Login", "Usuario Válido PARABÉNS ");
                else
                    mensagemExibir("Login", "Usuario Inválido ????");
            }
            catch(Exception erro)
            {
                Log.i("erro", "erro = "+erro);
                Toast.makeText(Logar.this, "Erro.: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;

        }


}
   public void mensagemExibir(String titulo, String texto)
   {
        AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(Logar.this);
        mensagem.setTitle(titulo);
        mensagem.setMessage(texto);
        mensagem.setNeutralButton("OK",null);
        mensagem.show();
   }
});
}
}
```

I will apreciate all the help. Thank You.

Comment: Your logcat will hold priceless clues. Please post it for us all to share in the bounty!

Comment: You aren't creating an instance of and executing LoginTask at any point

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091341/what-is-the-way-to-run-a-new-thread-and-a-ui-thread-in-android/16091615#16091615) about starting and using an `AsyncTask`. You will want to also read the part about not updating the `UI` in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call

```
new LoginTask().execute();
```

somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To start the `AsyncTask` you need to call its [`execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) method (or maybe `executeOnExecutor`), which is not visible in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show an AlertDialog from inside the doInBackground method.

Showing an alert dialog needs to be done on the UI thread, so you should return a result from your doInBackground method, and handle the result (and show the alert dialog) in the onPostExecute method.

Comment: This is good extra advice but doesn't solve the problem at hand. The task is never executed

Comment: It's not really clear from the question whether the app just stops(i.e. crashes), or whether it stops because he hasn't executed the task. In any case it will crash once he executes the task.

Comment: I agree with both points. I'm just saying the task is never executed from the code given. The `Toast` will also make it crash.