# Android HTTPGET request error, values not goin to server when click on login button

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I'm trying to write a code which signups a user. The php script is running fine. But code is android code is not working. Values not going on server.

```
package com.androidexample.httpgetexample;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpGetAndroidExample extends Activity {

TextView content;
EditText fname,email,login,pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_http_get_android_example);

    content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
    fname   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    email   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    login   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginname);
    pass    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);


    saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
            //ALERT MESSAGE
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please wait, connecting to server.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try{    

            String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(login.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
            String fnameValue = URLEncoder.encode(fname.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
            String emailValue = URLEncoder.encode(email.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
            String passValue  = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String URL = "http://nishtha.comze.com/log.php?user="+loginValue+"&name="+fnameValue+
                        "&email="+emailValue+"&pass="+passValue;

                //Log.d("httpget", URL);
                try
                {
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpget);
                    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
                    String SetServerString = "";
                    SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
                    content.setText(SetServerString);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    content.setText("Fail!");
                }
            }
            catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
            {
                content.setText("Fail22");
            }       
        }
    });  
}
}
```

When I run the code it olways display "Fail"

Comment: [Don't do network stuff on the UI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091341/what-is-the-way-to-run-a-new-thread-and-a-ui-thread-in-android/16091615#16091615)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AsyncTask<> or IntentService to handle your request.